# SQL server 2012 how to apply a check constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask if it is possible to apply a check constraint on multiple columns using one statement. I mean instead of adding a constraint for each column.

Scenario:
I have a table named 'Buyer' and contains these colums: BuyerId, BuyerName, BuyerSurname, BuyerEmail & BuyerAddress.

I need to apply a no empty string check constraints on BuyerName, BuyerSurname & BuyerEmail columns only.

Can this be done at one go instead of one constraint for each column?

Thanks for your help in advance

Kevin

Comment: You might want to run an AND isValidEmail regexp on the email also? The email might be fictitious, but it's no harm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table-level check constraint with multiple columns specified in the expression in order to avoid separate check constraints.

This example will not allow an empty string, all spaces, or `NULL` in these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Buyer(
      BuyerId int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Buyer PRIMARY KEY
    , BuyerName varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , BuyerSurname varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , BuyerEmail varchar(50) NULL
    , BuyerAddress varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CK_Buyer_BuyerName_BuyerSurname_BuyerEmail_NotEmpty CHECK
        ('' NOT IN (BuyerName,BuyerSurname,BuyerEmail) )
    );
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for the guidance am still new to how this website works. Thanks again.